# MVC get data from dynamic field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamic, get

I'm very new in MVC :(

I created a dynamic form by cloning a principal DIV element and its elements. The elements are combobox, textbox and a date textbox.  When I create a new "clone", the DIV every member of itself has an incremental ID like tab_Container, tab_Container_1, text, text1, combo, combo1, etc...  Now, I'm trying to get the values of each member in the Divs into the controller.

Googling I find something like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewEntry(Model Entry)
    {

        Control myControl = new Control();
        myControl.FindControl("Text0");

        if (myControl != null)
        {
        /// apparently, find the control,here i wanna to get the value of each field !! ¿?
          /// do i have to create a list[] ... exist something like Entry.Text0 = myControl.value? 
        }
        else
        {
           Response.Write("Control not found");
        }

        return View(Entry);
    }
```

Any suggestion?  Is Control the best option? Do I have to do something else in Javascript code?

Comment: What does `Control` class do ? You know that ASP.NET MVC does not have controls like web forms. Rite ?

Comment: What is `Control`?  What's in the `Entry` model that's being passed to the method here?  What's in the actual form post?

Comment: I try to use the Control.FinControl (method) of  using System.Web.UI.WebControls

Comment: @Shyju maybe is that my problem, I used Control.FindControl (Method) of using System.Web.UI.WebControls ...

Comment: MVC does not have any controls like web forms. You need to use the form elements /write markup as needed

Comment: @Shyju Something like: ` if (HttpContext.Request.RequestType == "POST")
         {
            // If the request is POST, get the values from the form
            var id = Request.Form["id"]; }  ` ?

Comment: Use a view model and take advantage of mvc model binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's normally better to have some sort of Model / ViewModel this situation is a bit different. MVC binds on the "Name" property of your form inputs.

So say for instance your razor syntax generates something like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="input1" />
    <input type="text" name="input2" />
    <!-- etc etc etc -->
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

since this is dynamically generated and you don't have a model that would cleanly bind to this. You can use the `FormCollection` type as the parameter of your action. This gives you a collection of all items posted to the server that you could then loop through or peer into to get the properties that you want.

```
public ActionResult myAction(FormCollection collection)
{
    var value = collection["input1"];
    var value2 = collection["input2"];

    return View();
}
```